# Мерцает загруженная картинка при наборе текста

Tags: дефект, дизайн, загрузка-изображения

Если я уже загрузил картинку, а потом пишу текст вопроса, то всё мигает и прыгает, причём, даже в том случае, если сама загруженная картинка не меняется:

> [image: скринвидео]

Comment: У меня не проявляется. Какой бровзер?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, хром. Картинка мигает в любом случае, но прыгать будет в зависимости от положения скролла на странице.